# Google map location crash

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager, android-location

I have set my activity to automatically set location, and i put a dialog when the GPS is not enabled  says. The application works as well as the device GPS got the location data but when there is no GPS data the application crashed.

here is my code

```
public class Newtab extends FragmentActivity {

String lat;
String longi;
String Name;
String cate;
private Map<Marker, Class> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, Class>();






 private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

 /////Main activity/////////
public void mainactivity(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Newtab.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
//////About//////
public void about(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Newtab.this, About.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter1;


private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}





private GoogleMap mMap;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();



    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



    if (locationManager!=null){
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Data pending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Global.able= 1;
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        Global.able=0;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (Global.itemsl!=null){
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < Global.itemsl.length(); i++) {
                            try {


                                final JSONObject obj = Global.itemsl.getJSONObject(i);
                                final Movie movie = new Movie();
                              movie.setCATEGORY(obj.getString("CATEGORY"));
                                lat=   movie.setLATITUDE(obj.getString("LATITUDE"));
                           longi=   movie.setLATITUDE(obj.getString("LONGITUDE"));
                           Name = movie.setNAME(obj.getString("NAME"));
                           cate = movie.setCATEGORY(obj.getString("CATEGORY"));
                       double latt=Double.parseDouble(lat);
                           double longg=Double.parseDouble(longi);




                           if(Global.able==0){
                           mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(36.1911,44.0092) , 6) );
                           }






                           final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt, longg)).title(obj.getString("NAME"));
                           mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {


                                String test=marker.getTitle();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < Global.itemsl.length(); i++) {
                                        try {


                                            JSONObject obj = Global.itemsl.getJSONObject(i);

                                            Name = movie.setNAME(obj.getString("NAME"));
                                            String DESCRIPTION = movie.setNAME(obj.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
                                            String IMAGELINK = movie.setNAME(obj.getString("IMAGELINK"));

                                        String PHONES = movie.setPHONES(obj.getString("PHONES"));
                                        String EMAILS =    movie.setEMAILS(obj.getString("EMAILS"));
                                     String ADDRESS =   movie.setADDRESS(obj.getString("ADDRESS"));
                                     String LATITUDE =   movie.setLATITUDE(obj.getString("LATITUDE"));
                                   String LONGITUDE =     movie.setLONGITUDE(obj.getString("LONGITUDE"));

                                   String FACEBOOK=    movie.setFACEBOOK(obj.getString("FACEBOOK"));
                                  String  INSTAGRAM =      movie.setINSTAGRAM(obj.getString("INSTAGRAM"));
                                  String TWITTER =      movie.setTWITTER(obj.getString("TWITTER"));
                                   String WEBSITE =     movie.setWEBSITE(obj.getString("WEBSITE"));


                                            if(arg0.getTitle().equals(Name)){

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Newtab.this, SingleItemView.class);

                                                intent.putExtra("NAME",Name);
                                                 // Start SingleItemView Class
                                                intent.putExtra("DESCRIPTION", DESCRIPTION);
                                                intent.putExtra("EMAILS", EMAILS);
                                                intent.putExtra("ADDRESS", ADDRESS);
                                                intent.putExtra("IMAGELINK", IMAGELINK);
                                                intent.putExtra("PHONES", PHONES);
                                                intent.putExtra("LATITUDE", LATITUDE);
                                                intent.putExtra("LONGITUDE", LONGITUDE);
                                                intent.putExtra("FACEBOOK", FACEBOOK);
                                                intent.putExtra("INSTAGRAM", INSTAGRAM);
                                                intent.putExtra("TWITTER", TWITTER);
                                                intent.putExtra("WEBSITE", WEBSITE);

                                                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);





                                                 startActivity(intent);




                                            }










                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                                return false;
                                }
                            });





                        Bitmap bmImg = Ion.with(getBaseContext())
                                .load("http://app-chef.com/SquareCard/App/Categories_icons/"+cate+".png").asBitmap().get();


                           marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImg));

                        // adding marker
                        mMap.addMarker(marker);

                        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


                           mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


                        if (Global.able==1){   
                           LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                           Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                           double mylong = location.getLongitude();
                           double mylat = location.getLatitude();


                                 LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(mylat, mylong);
                           CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 15);
                           mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);


                        }




                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
    }

    }            




    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>Back  </font>"));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2d76ba")));




}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}




private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please Enable your GPS")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNegativeButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
        }
    });



    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.cancel();

        }



    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}






@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap != null) {
        return;
    }
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Initialize map options. For example:
    // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);






}
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`
double mylong = location.getLongitude();
double mylat = location.getLatitude();
```

never assume  `location` is not null, it can be null when the user does not have a GPS lock or it is disabled